# Does it make sense to upgrade the early weapons?

Tags: mass-effect-3

On the Normandy you have the option to upgrade your weapons, e.g. your M-15 Vindicator I to the M-15 Vindicator II or higher. I'm wondering if it makes sense to already upgrade my early weapons to a high level, the upgrades seem to be reasonably affordable at this early stage.

But I don't know if I will be still running around with the same weapons as now in the near future, or if I will have found some far better ones quickly. In ME1 you found better weapons pretty often (until you got the high-level Spectre gear), while in ME2 most weapons were just different, and not necessarily superior in every regard.

So, are the later weapons far superior to the early ones, or mostly just different?

Comment: One thing to note is that credits feel *much* more abundant this time around, and weapon upgrades for the early weapons seem quite cheap. I upgraded my starting shotgun to max rank for fewer credits than I got as a reward for my first mission.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Does that mean there's less grinding than previous ME titles?  Oh please let it be so...  The Mako was one of the worst ideas in RPG history.  M35 = timesink.

Comment: @Steve define grinding. I'm getting lots of credits from planet scanning, which is 'quick' but monotonous.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Yeah, I would call that grinding.  But I can't be too critical.  They never make you grind for levels, just for resources, and in general 2 was MUCH better than 1 so I'm just hoping 3 is that much better than 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The weapons in Mass Effect 3 are designed to be relatively equivalent. Sure, the starting weapons aren't the flashiest or the ones with the coolest specials, but they get the job done. Perhaps more importantly, *they are some of the lightest weapons available*.

So as to whether the early weapons are "worth" it, it depends a lot on whether you're making much use of the Weight power recharge bonus (or not using it at all). They're often the best weapons if you're just looking to cover a particular category as a backup weapon in case of ammo problems.

Comment: Yup, their weight is super handy. The Avenger is surprisingly decent compared to the other assault rifles, accuracy-wise.

Answer (score 0):

also, given that a single upgrade (i.e. shotgun choke) can be reused on any weapon of that type, there is no reason NOT to purchase or use upgrades because you can always reapply them to newer versions of that weapon.

Comment: I believe the OP was referring to Upgrading a weapon (I -> II -> III etc.) not Mods which are what you're referring to.